# How to use jQuery DataTables with Server-Side Processing C# and WebMethod?

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

Is there anyway to use **DataTables** jquery with C# Server-Side Processing examples for pagination, sort, search, and without using LINQ ?

Comment: search jquery datatable functions for editing sorting etc and override them with your functions.In your function use jquery ajax and make server side requests

Comment: Thank you Muhammad, but you have any samples for that?

Comment: for jquery ajax call using web method,have a look on this http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

Comment: i know how to call jquery ajax, but how to merge with datatables functions?

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution and its worked for me:

```
$('#usersList').dataTable({
                        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                        "bDestroy": true,
                        "bProcessing": true,
                        "bServerSide": true,
                        "bDeferRender": true,
                        "aaSorting": [[2, 'asc']],
                        "oLanguage": {
                            "sProcessing": '<div class="splash-title"><img src="images/loading-bars.svg" width="64" height="64" /></div'
                        },
                        "sAjaxSource": "AJUserManagement.aspx/GetAJUsers",
                        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                            $.ajax({
                                "dataType": 'json',
                                "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                "type": "GET",
                                "url": sSource,
                                "data": aoData,
                                "success": function (msg) {
                                    var json = msg.d;
                                    fnCallback(json);
                                }
                            });
                        }});
```

json should be a json object included a list of object, **recordsTotal** = total records, should be from data source and **recordsFiltered** = filtered records, should be from data source